# check SMTP authentication without sending email and without using pear in PHP

Tags: php, email, smtp, phpmailer, swiftmailer

How to check SMTP authentication without sending email and without using pear in PHP. Is their any way to check the authentication with host,port,username and password?

I checked swiftmailer, it says authentication is on sending the email.
http://swiftmailer.org/docs/sending.html#smtp-with-a-username-and-password

Same on phpmailer also.
https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/smtp.phps

Comment: You can authenticate and then close the connection. The issue is that most libraries won't try to connect and authenticate until you tell them to send. You can use the SMTP class in PHPmailer to connect, authenticate and then close the connection. Exactly how you drive it should be apparent from looking at how PHPMailer uses it.

Answer (score 2):

Admittedly, this is not the cleanest solution, but it will work.  Copied below is an `expect` script that will connect to an SMTP server, attempt to authenticate, then quit the session and disconnect.  If the last line of output from the `expect` script is `235 2.7.0 Authentication successful` (or another similar response with a response code beginning with 2xx), then the authentication was successful using the credentials provided, otherwise, the authentication failed.  You can call this `expect` script from your PHP script using `shell_exec()` and parse the output to test if it is possible to authenticate with an SMTP server given a set of credentials.

```
                #!/usr/bin/expect
                set mailserver "smtp.smtpserver.com";         #fqdn of SMTP server
                set credentials "AG1xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxDNy";  #this string should be "\0username\0password" base64-encoded.

                spawn telnet $mailserver 25
                expect "failed" {
                                send_user "$mailserver: connect failed\n"
                                exit
                        } "2?? *" {
                        } "4?? *"   {
                                exit
                        } "refused" {
                                send_user "$mailserver: connect refused\n"
                                exit
                        } "closed" {
                                send_user "$mailserver: connect closed\n"
                                exit
                        } timeout {
                                send_user "$mailserver: connect to port 25 timeout\n"
                                exit
                        }
                send "HELO foo.com\r"
                expect "2?? *" {
                } "5?? *" {
                        exit
                } "4?? *" {
                        exit
                }

                send "AUTH PLAIN $credentials\r";
                expect "2?? *" {
                } "5?? *" {
                        exit
                } "4?? *" {
                        exit
                }

                send "QUIT\r"
                exit
```

Comment: FYI, This script will attempt to connect to the remote SMTP host on port 25 without SSL or TLS.  If you want to connect on another port using SSL or TLS (such as port 465, 587, etc), then instead of spawning telnet, spawn openssl as shown here: http://www.madboa.com/geek/openssl/#cs-smtp

Answer (score 1):

Using [PHPmailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) can test the connection without send an email.

i add the function otuside of the class (but can use it in a controller without problems)

```
    /*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| USE in file
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Need add "use" this because:
|  - PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception -> catch exceptions of PHPmailer
|  - PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP -> Do the conexión of smtp server
|
 */
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;


/**
 * Test connection SMTP
 * @param String $route Host route
 * @param Integer $port Port to connect
 * @param String $userName Email or user name
 * @param String $userPass Password from user
 * @param String $from Mail from 
 * @param String $to Mail to
 * @return Array ['status'=>boolean,'logs'=>array]
 */
function testSMTP($route,$port,$userName = null,$userPass = null,$from=null,$to=null){
    //SMTP needs accurate times, and the PHP time zone MUST be set
    //This should be done in your php.ini, but this is how to do it if you don't have access to that
    date_default_timezone_set('Etc/UTC');
    $logs = [];
    $status_ok = false;

    //Create a new SMTP instance
    $logs = NewLog($logs,"Starting SMTP test");
    $smtp = new SMTP();

    //Enable to show all logs while load page
    //$smtp->do_debug = SMTP::DEBUG_CONNECTION;

    try {
        //Connect to an SMTP server
        $logs = NewLog($logs,"Testing SMTP connection");
        if (!$smtp->connect($route, $port)) {
            throw new Exception('Connect failed');
        }
        //Say hello
        if (!$smtp->hello(gethostname())) {
            throw new Exception('EHLO failed: ' . $smtp->getError()['error']);
        }
        $logs = NewLog($logs,"SMTP connected");
        //Get the list of ESMTP services the server offers
        $e = $smtp->getServerExtList();
        //If server can do TLS encryption, use it
        if (is_array($e) && array_key_exists('STARTTLS', $e)) {
            $tlsok = $smtp->startTLS();
            if (!$tlsok) {
                throw new Exception('Failed to start encryption: ' . $smtp->getError()['error']);
            }
            //Repeat EHLO after STARTTLS
            if (!$smtp->hello(gethostname())) {
                throw new Exception('EHLO (2) failed: ' . $smtp->getError()['error']);
            }
            //Get new capabilities list, which will usually now include AUTH if it didn't before
            $e = $smtp->getServerExtList();
        }
        //If server supports authentication, do it (even if no encryption)
        if(!empty($userName) && !empty($userPass)){
            if (is_array($e) && array_key_exists('AUTH', $e)) {
                if ($smtp->authenticate($userName, $userPass)) {
                    $logs = NewLog($logs,"SMTP user loged");
                } else {
                    throw new Exception('Authentication failed: ' . $smtp->getError()['error']);
                }
            }
        }
        //checkeamos el RCPT TO y MAIL FROM con los metodos de 
        if (!empty($to) && !empty($from)) {
            $logs = NewLog($logs,"Testing SMTP send email");
            if(!$smtp->mail($from)){
                throw new Exception('MAIL FROM: ' . $smtp->getError()['error']);
            }
            if(!$smtp->recipient($to)){
                throw new Exception('RCPT TO: ' . $smtp->getError()['error']);
            }
            $logs = NewLog($logs,"Test SMTP send it's ok");
        }
        $logs = NewLog($logs,"End SMTP test - OK");
        $status_ok = true;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $logs = NewLog($logs,'SMTP error: ' . $e->getMessage(), "\n");
    }
    //Whatever happened, close the connection.
    $smtp->quit();

    //return result
    return [
        'logs' => $logs,
        'status' => $status_ok
    ];

}

function NewLog ($listLogs,$log){
    $listLogs[] = "[".date('Y.m.d H:i:s')."] ".$log;
    return $listLogs;
}
```

You can use this function otuside a controller but it's better have it in a class.